# Handling Parent function call in Child in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, methods, parent-child

Is it possible to create a method in Parent class in React and then pass it on to the Child and use it there.

So basically I would create a button in my Parent class, pass the function on to the Child and when the Button is clicked, the child will know about it and Parent will not really care for it?

```
class App extends Component {
  clickMade = () => {
    //This should be left empty
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Button onClick={this.clickMade}>Click me </Button>
        <Child clickMade={this.clickMade} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And the Child:

```
class Child extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClick = this.props.clickMade.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Click in child");
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default Child;
```

And a sandbox for this: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-darkness-iywsg?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can render Button on Child component and you can handle it's click event in parent

Comment: An alternate is If you want the Child to know that parent is clicked, you can call child's function from the parent by calling its a reference

Comment: Well there is a reason but its quite hard to explain.. but i was just wondering if that case is even possible.

Comment: Yes, if you want the Child to know that parent is clicked, you can call the child's function from the parent by calling its a reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  clickMade = () => {
    this.childRef.handleClick();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Button onClick={this.clickMade}>Click me </Button>
        <Child
          ref={ref => {
           this.childRef = ref;
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```